# How to remove npm files from meteor build

Tags: meteor, npm

After upgrading Meteor to 1.3.x version NPM really came to play. But as always there is back side of the coin: build size.
On meteor 1.2.x build size is ~50MB, ~7k files
On meteor 1.3.x build size is ~190MB, **~27k** files.

**Twenty seven thousand files**. That's quite a number. Not to mention path size exceeding 256 (a trouble for windows users).
I've dig into what meteor included into the build and it seems that all the npm_modules is here with all the stuff that is need to build some modules and their dependencies.

The question is: how to build meteor app without unnessesary npm files, leaving only the ones that are actually used by app at runtime?

Update:
On meteor 1.4.1_3 if you create a simple project `meteor create dummy-project` and go through all the common stuff like `npm meteor install` and `meteor npm prune --production` and them make a bundle out of it with `meteor build c:\dummy --directory` you will get a folder with the same 7k files and almost 2k folders (by the way it will not run `node main.js` out of the box as you might expect). If you tinker through folders you can find babel compiler inside that takes ~3.5k files.

**Why do I need babel compiler inside compiled app?**

Comment: what do you mean by unnecessary npm files?  If you're not using a package, uninstall it.

Comment: I mean that npm packages are not just 1(or some) js files + 1(or some) html/css files, but they contain a lot of files needed to build that package and package dependencies inside. I.e.: angular2-color-picker is 30mb size with 2100 files inside: there is another node_modules inside with it's own angular package!

Comment: Another example: d3js: npm package is 1.78MB size with 309 files - d3.min.js is only one file 150kB size.

Answer (score -1):

To gain an introspective of your packages,

```
npm list --depth 0
```

to see the current packages in your project with only one level.

Inspect that list, and decide if you don't need a package and uninstall it.

You can also use other flags such as

```
npm list --depth 1 #the number represents the max depth
npm list --long true #for more information about the packages
npm list --global true #to check your global packages. 
npm help-search <searchTerm>
```

Hope that helps you gain more insight in your packages. [help-search Link](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/help-search)

You may see that multiple packages depends on the same packages, and then it's up to you to decided what your application needs to run successfully.

**Edit 1**

You can exclude the packages inside your devDependencies, so that when you're publishing/deploying your code you have a cleaner package.

You do this by using `npm prune --production`  - that removes all your devDependencies, and will require your users to do a `npm install` for your package to work. For info [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/prune)

Comment: I can clearly see my first level packages in package.json file of my project. See my comment to original post.

Comment: Like I said, you will repeated dependencies, and it's up to you to decide what to use or if it easier to just implement yourself.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning "prune" option. I'm alredy doing packaging for electron with prune option turned on. Still no luck reducing file count and size.